# setState not updating when passing variable to function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-web

when I pass the variables to a function that has a setState method, it does not update, when I call the variable directly from the same function it works fine, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here:

code:

```
 _startFilePicker(Uint8List chosenFile, var color, IconData iconData) async {
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.click();

uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
  // read file content as dataURL
  final files = uploadInput.files;
  if (files.length == 1) {
    final file = files[0];
    FileReader reader = FileReader();

    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      setState(() {
        print("on load set state");
        chosenFile = reader.result;
        iconData = Icons.done;
        color = Colors.green[500];
      });
    });

    reader.onError.listen((fileEvent) {
      setState(() {
        print("error");
        //"Some Error occured while reading the file";
      });
    });

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
});
```

}

when I call the _startFilePicker(attachmentOne, firstAttachmentColor, firstAttachment) the variables are not updated in the setState method called in function, however when I call those variables directly inside the function like so:

```
reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
      setState(() {
        print("on load set state");
        attachmentOne = reader.result;
        firstAttachment = Icons.done;
        firstAttachmentColor = Colors.green[500];
      });
    });
```

The button that is calling this function:

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: Icon(iconda),
    onPressed: () => setState(() {
         _startFilePicker(chosenfile, color, iconda);
         }),
          style: ButtonStyle(
           backgroundColor:
           MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color),
         ),
),
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

**Note: all code and variables are in the same class state.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
_startFilePicker(Uint8List chosenFile, var color, IconData iconData) async {
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
uploadInput.click();
uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
// read file content as dataURL
final files = uploadInput.files;
if (files.length == 1) {
final file = files[0];
FileReader reader = FileReader();
reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) { 
    print("on load set state");
    chosenFile = reader.result;
    iconData = Icons.done;
    color = Colors.green[500];
 setState((){});
});

reader.onError.listen((fileEvent) { 
    print("error");
    //"Some Error occured while reading the file";      
});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

}
});

Comment: Whilst this code may be correct and may solve the issue, you should always explain what the code does and why/how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  _startFilePicker() async {
  InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
  uploadInput.click();
 uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
// read file content as dataURL
final files = uploadInput.files;
if (files.length == 1) {
  final file = files[0];
  FileReader reader = FileReader();
  reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
    print("on load set state");
   return [reader.result,Icons.done,Colors.green[500]];
  });

  reader.onError.listen((fileEvent) {
    print("error");        //"Some Error occured while reading the file";
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}});

}
// then pass your value like this...


 renderr() async {
 attachmentOne = _startFilePicker()[0];
 firstAttachment = _startFilePicker()[1];
 firstAttachmentColor = _startFilePicker()[2];
 setState() {};
 }
```

just call renderr();

This should give you an idea